Pinia store contains null values if referenced from onMounted hook
I'm having an issue where my Pinia store will contain null for each of its state properties if I try to access it via onMounted hook. It's a little more complex than that. Here is the call stack basically

Component (OnMounted) calls
Composable calls
Pinia Store

Component
onMounted(async () => {
    const resp = await $authFetch(config.functionsBaseUrl + 'v1/account/settings',
    {
        method: 'GET'
    }).catch(e => {
        toast.show({
            type: 'error',
            title: 'Error',
            content: e.data
        });

        return null;
    })

    if (resp === null)
    return;

    userSetings.value = resp;
})

Composable
export async function $authFetch<T>(
    request: Parameters<typeof $fetch<T>>[0],
    opts?: Parameters<typeof $fetch<T>>[1],
) {
    const auth = useAuth(useNuxtApp().$pinia);

    const shouldRefreshToken = () => {
        const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

        // Calculate the time difference between expiration time and current time
        console.log('calculating', auth.tokenExpiration);
        const timeDifference = auth.tokenExpiration - currentTime;
        console.log('time diff', timeDifference);
        // Check if the token is expiring within the next 5 minutes (300 seconds)
        return timeDifference <= 300;
    }

    console.log('authFetch', auth, auth.tokenExpiration, shouldRefreshToken());

    if (auth.tokenExpiration && shouldRefreshToken()) {
        const url = useRuntimeConfig().public.functionsBaseUrl + 'v1/auth/refresh';
        console.log('refreshing', url);
        const resp = await $fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: {
                refreshToken: auth.refreshToken,
                idToken: auth.token
            },
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.token}`
            }
        }).catch(e => {
            if (e.data === 'Unauthorized') {
                //refresh token has expired, log the user out
                auth.$reset();
                const cookie = useCookie('auth');
                cookie.value = null;
            }
        });

        auth.token = resp.Token;
        auth.tokenExpiration = resp.Expiration;
    }

    return $fetch<T>(request, {
        ...opts,
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.token}`,
            ...opts?.headers,
        },
    });
}

Store
export const useAuth = defineStore('auth', {
    state: () => ({
        token: null,
        refreshToken: null,
        email: null,
        userId: null,
        firstName: null,
        lastName: null,
        organizationId: null,
        organizationName: null,
        organizationIndustry: null,
        tokenExpiration: null
    }),
    actions: {
        setLoginPayload(loginResponse) {
            this.token = loginResponse.Token;
            this.refreshToken = loginResponse.RefreshToken;
            this.email = loginResponse.Email;
            this.userId = loginResponse.UserId;
            this.firstName = loginResponse.FirstName;
            this.lastName = loginResponse.LastName;
            this.organizationId = loginResponse.OrganizationId;
            this.organizationName = loginResponse.CompanyName;
            this.organizationIndustry = loginResponse.Industry;
            this.tokenExpiration = loginResponse.Expiration;
            console.log('set token expiration', loginResponse.Expiration);

            //set in localstorage
            const cookie = useCookie('auth');
            cookie.value = loginResponse;
        }
    }
})

If I wrap the code inside the onMounted function in a 1 second delay, the store values are no longer empty
I can't find anything anywhere that explains that Pinia needs some time to "be ready" or a way to await it to "be ready"
Is there anything obvious here why my store is empty when called in onMount?
EDIT 1
Just for clarity I'm showing the code that actually sets the store.
After login.. login.vue
const login = async () => {
  loggingIn.value = true;
  var url = useRuntimeConfig().public.functionsBaseUrl + "v1/auth/login";
  var response = await $fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
      email: email.value,
      password: password.value
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    toast.show({
      title: 'Login Error',
      content: error.data,
      type: 'error',
      timeout: 5000
    })

    loggingIn.value = false;
  });

  if (response) {
    auth.setLoginPayload(response);
    toast.show({
      content: `Welcome ${auth.firstName}!`,
      type: 'success',
      title: 'Success'
    });

    const router = useRouter();

    setTimeout(() => {
      router.push('/documents');
    }, 1000);
  }
};

In case the user refreshes the browser app.vue
onMounted(() => {
  const jsonAuth = useCookie('auth');
  console.log('jsonauth', jsonAuth.value);
  //keep the user logged in
  //TODO, figure out what happens once the refresh token expires. at this point the refresh mechanism will no longer work,
  //we need a way to detect this and send the user to the login screen
  if (jsonAuth.value) {
    const auth = useAuth();
    auth.setLoginPayload(jsonAuth.value);
  }

})


in the code provided it does not look like you are doing anything to set the store values. How/when are you using setLoginPayload ?

There are two ways. When the user logins initially the store values are set. I also set a cookie at this time. If the browser is refreshed I pull the values from the cookie and reset it on the store.

Figured it out. Of course it's my own ignorance if not knowing how Nuxt3/Vue3 works. I'm a back end dev so apologies. In case it helps anyone else here was the issue.
In vue, the child components onMount hooks run before the parent's do
In essence, I had code setting the auth store from a cookie in my app.vue (main vue where I call ). This was being called after my page mounted and thus the auth store was null if the user had finished refreshing the page.
The solution was to add this cookie code in the onBeforeMount hook of the app.vue which will run before any child component onMount runs
